# parsing CFMutableDictionary keys

Tags: c++, string, macos, parsing, macos-carbon

I am using IOKit to obtain some information

```
kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, IOServiceNameMatching("AppleUSBEHCI"), &io_objects);
[snip]
kr = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties(child, &child_props,  kCFAllocatorDefault, kNilOptions );
            NSLog(@"Child props: %@", child_props);
            //release child_props
        }

        IOObjectRelease(io_service);
    }

sn = (CFStringRef) CFDictionaryGetValue(child_props, CFSTR("IOCFPlugInTypes"));
NSLog(@"sn: %@", sn);
```

I am going after the key `IOCFPlugInTypes`:

It works, I get back:

`{
    "9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861" = "IOUSBFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOUSBLib.bundle";
}`

But what I need to do next is just get the part that says: `9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861`

Can anyone help me work through this?

Answer (score 1):

Here CFDictionaryGetValue is returning another object of type CFDictionaryRef (not string as you type casted). So "9dc7b780-9ec0-11d4-a54f-000a27052861" is the key in that dictionary. You should be doing something like below:

```
CFTypeRef sn = (CFTypeRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(child_props, CFSTR("IOCFPlugInTypes"));
if (CFDictionaryGetTypeID() == CFGetTypeID(sn))
{
    int dictSize = CFDictionaryGetCount(sn);
    CFStringRef * keys = (CFStringRef*)malloc (dictSize * sizeof (CFStringRef));
    CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues (sn, keys, NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < dictSize; i++)
    {
        CFShow(keys[i]);
    }
}
```